# Rails 4 - Timer (jQuery.Countdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, timer

I'm trying to create a timer into my Rails. But I'm getting this error:

```
jquery.countdown.min.self-6add0e5….js?body=1:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPlugin' of undefined
```

I add :

- `jquery.countdown.min.js` into `assets/javascripts`
- `jquery.coundown.css` into `assets/stylesheets`
- `jQuery.js` is there and working properly
- Into `application.js` - `//= require jquery.countdown.min`
- Into `application.scss` - `*= require jquery.countdown`

Then i create:

**VIEW**

```
<th width="20%" class="timeRem" data-countdown-until="<%= 10.days.from_now %>"></th>
```

**timer.js.coffee**

```
 Timers =
  init: ->
    @initCountdownUntil()
    @initCountdownSince()

  initCountdownUntil: ->
    $('[data-countdown-until]').each (index, element) ->
      $element = $(element)
      date = new Date($element.data('countdown-until'))
      $element.countdown(until: date)

  initCountdownSince: ->
    $('[data-countdown-since]').each (index, element) ->
      $element = $(element)
      date = new Date($element.data('countdown-since'))
      $element.countdown(since: date)

window.Timers = Timers
```

Don't rally know how to fix it, appreciate any advice and help with that.

Comment: Does `jquery.countdown.min.js` appears after `jquery.min.js` in your rendered page?

Comment: Yeah, i solved it by ordering plugin js first and countdown second..

Comment: Added it as an answer for future Googlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our comments, `jquery.countdown.min.js` file should be placed before `jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 2):

You place the scripts on the page in this order `jquery.js` then `jquery.plugin.js` then `jquery.countdown.js`

[[image: ]]

ref: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html